# Changing a div and its content automatically once per given cycle

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to have a div and its contents (images class and associated text) change automatically every week to different preconfigured content? Can u use jquery to do this?

Note: Thank you dear smart bucks for the witty comments:-)

To clarify. I have a web page with a picture of a featured artist and his/her bio underneath. I would like to have a different artist featured every week with their own bio and image. I can do it manually but would prefer it if the artist image and bio changed automatically every week cycling between different artists. The content is in a div and I wanted to know if I can cycle the content of the different artists using jquery or some other process?

Comment: Is that all? Looks like your question is not complete.

Comment: "every week to..."? I think we need more information.

Comment: seems complete enough though .. could rephrase like 'can i use jquery to trigger an event every 7 days?'

Comment: Could you provide more information as to the environment your site is in. What technologies you're currently using, do you also use a server-side language, how you might store the preconfigured content, or if that's a part to the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want something like this. Say you have three divs you want to rotate between each week:

```
<div class="weekly week-1"> Buy our things! </div>
<div class="weekly week-2"> Save 20% today! </div>
<div class="weekly week-3"> Free kitten with every widget! </div>
```

You can show and hide the div based on the week like this:

```
// Get the number of the week since the epoch.
var week = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));

// Show one div per week.
$('.weekly').hide();
$('.weekly .week-' + (week % 3 + 1)).show();
```

Note that the epoch (Dec 31 1969) was the middle of the week so this is when your banners will change.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am looking for, although I am not sure I get the epoch's relevance :-)

Comment: [The epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) is a reference point for dates. The internal structure of a JavaScript Date is probably an integer of the number of milliseconds since the Epoch. On my browser, zero seconds after the epoch is Dec 31, 1969: `alert(new Date(0))`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably better served by a server-side solution. However, you can use something like the following for a quick hack:

```
var now = new Date();

Date.prototype.getDOY = function() {
var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
return Math.ceil((this - onejan) / 86400000);
}

var day = now.getDOY();

var week = Math.floor(day / 7);

switch(week)
{
case 1:
  // First Week
  break;
case 2:
  // Second week
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup><sub><s>yes</s> <s>maybe</s> <s>unlikely</s> definitely</sub></sup>

---

In order to avoid downloading all sorts of unnecessary data, just create a different HTML file on your server for each artist. Each file should contain *only* the content you want. No `<html>` `<head>` `<body>` tags.

Label the files consistently, ending with a number, like: `artist_0.html`, `artist_1.html` etc..

Then to rotate them, do this:

```
var today = new Date();
var beginning = new Date(today.getFullYear(),0,1);
var dayOfYear = Math.floor((((today - beginning) / 60000 ) / 60 ) / 24);
var weekNumber = Math.floor(dayOfYear / 7);

var numberOfArtists = 7;  // Total quantity of artists (indexed 0 - 6)

var artistURL = "/path/to/artist_" + (weekNumber % 7) + ".html"; // Build the URL

$(function() {
    $('#my_highlighted_artist').load(artistURL); // Load the proper artist
});                                              //    on page load
```

It won't matter how many artists you have. It will always cycle to the next one (though the cycle will start over at the first one on Jan 1.

Comment: loL! i just refrained from writing exactly that :)

Comment: See, now I would have said only on days that end in `y`. Like tomorrow, it won't work (but Wednesday it will). ;-)

Comment: @Brad: Ah yes, and yesterday it would have.

Comment: Bwahahaahahah. SO needs a "Yes." auto-reply ;)